# LyX: How can I input a second paragraph in an enumerate item?

Tags: lyx, enumerate, paragraphs

In standard LaTeX, one can have paragraphs inside lists. For example

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Some text here.

        Second paragraph in this list item

    \item Second list item.
\end{enumerate}
```

produces

[image: Text]

Is it possible to achieve the same thing when using LyX? Pressing `Enter` while writing a list produces a new item of the list. How can I produce a new paragraph under the same item?

Comment: If you do "ctrl + <return>", does that do what you want?

Comment: @scottkosty Not really. It introduces a new line (\\ in the latex export), so the spacing is too small. Doing it twice results in an empty line, which is too much spacing.

Comment: Ah indeed. You need to nest Standard inside the inset. I wrote an answer with the steps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to "nest" a "Standard" paragraph inside the item. Here are the steps:

1. Start an itemize.
2. Write "Some text here.".
3. Press <kbd>Return</kbd>. (This will create a new item, but the next two steps will adjust it)
4. Change the layout to "Standard".
5. Press <kbd>Tab</kbd>. (This will nest it under the previous layout).
6. Press <kbd>Return</kbd>.
7. Write "Second list item."

Comment: Perfect solution. Note the *Tab* action may be disabled if a "display" mode math formula has been separated from the preceding line by a line return. Removing the line return will re-enable the command. [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjnxo.png). I don't understand the reason, but it works.

Answer (score 3):

One way to do this is to insert the TeX command `\par` in LyX, and continue writing on the same line. This is not "native LyX" though...